# AJAX open does not accept Servlet

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, servlets

I am currently making a small program using AJAX. I want to send a JSON String to a Servlet, but it doesn't work. In my browser I get the error *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"*

I'm guessing that this means, that it can't find the Servlet in the following line:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "../JSONServlet", true);
```

However, I have made similar programs before and never had this problem, so I don't know what to do to make it work.

My html and js files are in *Web Pages/ex06* and my Servlet is in *Source Packages/servlets/JSONServlet*, however I've tried moving it somewhere else (even though I have made programs that worked like this), but it didn't help.

This is the html and javascript:

```js
var xmlHttp;
window.onload = initAjax();

function initAjax() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {      
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {     // IE6 or older
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (ex) {                        // noch ältere MS Produkte
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    }
  }
}

function doJSON1() {
    
  var car = new Car("Mercedes", "SLK", 2012); // car erstellen
  var carAsJSON = JSON.stringify(car); // json-String machen
  alert("Car object as JSON:\n " + carAsJSON);
  
  xmlHttp.open("POST", "../JSONServlet", true); // here is the problem
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleObjectRequest;
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlHttp.send(carAsJSON); // json-String senden
  
}

function handleObjectRequest() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        
      jsontext = xmlHttp.responseText;
      alert(jsontext);
      var benz = JSON.parse(jsontext);
      var output = benz.brand + " " + benz.model;
      document.getElementById("serverResponse").innerHTML = output;
 
    }else{
        alert("nope");
    }
  }else{
      alert("...");
  }
  alert("state change");
}

function Car(brand, model, year, color) {
  this.brand = brand;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.color = color;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="JSON-Object senden&empfangen" onclick="doJSON1();"/>
```

This is the method in my Servlet:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());
    try {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // auto aus request erstellen
        Car car = gson.fromJson(isr, Car.class);

        // anderes auto schreiben
        Car car2 = new Car("audi", "tt", 2014);
        gson.toJson(car2, out);

    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String[] winter = gson.fromJson(isr, String[].class);
        String[] summer = {"Jun", "Jul", "Aug"};
        out.println(gson.toJson(summer));

    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

My Car class is a simple data class with getters and setters, a default constructor, a custom constructor, and a toString.

Comment: Your initAjax function is creating a new local variable `xmlhttp` (lowercase H) rather than using the declared global variable `xmlHttp`

Comment: `window.onload = initAjax();` <-- that is wrong. It is calling the function and assigning what it returns to window.onload, not calling the function on window load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an instance of the `XMLHttpRequest()` to use the `open()` method, so add the following line of code:

```
var  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Before you use the open() method like so:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "../JSONServlet", true);
```

**EDIT:** - You also have a typo as pointed out by @james before i did, in you're `initAjax` function you have a variable `xmlhttp` were as you're global variable is `xmlHttp` , both are not the same.

Comment: because the declared global variable is `xmlHttp` and the one initialized in the function is `xmlhttp`